# Jquery Validate Incompatible with Placeholder Polyfill? [IE9 Bug]

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, placeholder, polyfills

I'm currently using the [Placeholder Polyfill by Mathias Bynens](http://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) in combination with the [jquery.validate plugin (v1.11.1)](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and am running into a frustrating error with **Internet Explorer 9**.

I cannot get *required field* validation to work on my `type="password"` fields if they have a non-empty `placeholder` attribute defined. Once a value is input and the placeholder text disappears, the remaining validation works fine.

[Live Demo of this code can be found here](http://lysobey.com/placeholderValidatePassword)

**JS**

```
$('input').placeholder(); // init placeholder plugin
signupFormValidator = $('form').validate(); // init validation
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input class="required" type="text" name="test" id="test" placeholder="test"><br>
  <input class="required" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"><br>
  <input class="required" type="password" name="confirm"  id="confirm"  placeholder="confirm"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no clean solution, but I ended up using a work-around with some JS. Check out my new answer below.

Comment: @creativetim FYI - just discovered my hack/fix is broken in FF. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** this fix introduces bugs in Firefox. Please see comment below.

---

To deal with this, I ended up using some fairly hacky jQuery I baked myself:

```
$('#password, #confirm').keyup(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    if ($input.attr('type') === 'text') {
        if ($input.val().length > 0) {
            $input.attr('type', 'password');
        }
    } else if ($input.val() === "") {
        $input.attr('type', 'text');
    }
});
```

What this is doing, is setting the field `type` to "text" rather than "password", effectively clearing up that pesky placeholder issue.

Minor issue: the first character of the password displays as plain-text briefly when starting to enter text into the input.

Comment: FYI, just discovered this (probably) introduces a bug (so far only reproduced in Firefox). When typing quickly into the password field(s)  the cursor sometimes ends up in the middle of the word. I'll post back with any further findings / solutions.