# ASP Disable Password autocomplete in chrome

Tags: html, asp.net, google-chrome, autocomplete

I have tried to disable autocomplete password in google **chrome 69.0.3497.100** by using

> autocomplete="off"
>
> autocomplete="new-password"
>
> autocompletetype="Disabled"

but nothing helped.

I hope someone could help.

Comment: This a Html and browser thing and has nothing to do with ASP. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: try to delete the cache of the browser and try again by pressing crtl+F5

Comment: clearing cache doesn't help.. it's related to chrome password manager

Comment: See this workaround. You can create multiple hidden fields to trick the browser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945535/html-disable-password-manager

Comment: Samy Sammour ,I tried it but it didn't work as chrome now works on any password field

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Chrome issue.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off/37089477) on ways to get around it

Comment: yes it's known but all solutions in that post didn't work with me ..maybe because of  chrome updates.