# Preventing Browser Text Input Suggestions 2021 chrome version 88.0.4324.190

Tags: html, autosuggest

How To Preventing Browser Text Input Suggestions from browser cookie, `autocomplete="off"` and others are not work.. Chrome Version : 2021 chrome version **88.0.4324.190**

readonly is work for autofill its work proper, but autosuggestion is not.

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" style="background-color: white;" autocomplete="off">   
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="password" minlength="6" placeholder="Enter Password">
```

[image]

Comment: anybody help to solved this issue

Comment: Could you please give us some code?

Comment: @codeRdevelopR sure

Comment: this is really work for me now in version 88.0.4324.190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is here

change `type="password"` to `type="text"` and used in your input
`-webkit-text-security: disc !important;`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Password" name="password" minlength="6" placeholder="Enter Password" style="-webkit-text-security: disc !important;">
```

Comment: Happy To Help :)

Comment: its also work for mozila firefox browser latest version

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that still works in Chrome is creating random name not related to the field. Like `autocomplete="new-password"` to password field name.
Seems to be wrong, but it's a workaround.

So for your field named email, try to put `autocomplete="new-email"`.

Even as stated as working in the SO below, `autocomplete="off"` still buggy:
[Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30976223/1049870)

> Also note that `autocomplete="no"` will appear to work but `autocomplete="off"` will not for historical reasons. `autocomplete="no"` is you telling the browser that this field should be auto completed as a field called `"no"`. If you generate unique random autocomplete names you disable auto complete.

You need to keep in mind that's a feature from the Password Manager.
This is correctly stated here by Mozilla:
[Preventing autofilling with autocomplete="new-password"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password)

And why it's not always possible to prevent:
[Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#browser_compatibility)

> Note: In most modern browsers, setting autocomplete to "off" will not prevent a password manager from asking the user if they would like to save username and password information, or from automatically filling in those values in a site's login form. [See the autocomplete attribute and login fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#the_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields).

### Solution #1:

As you can see, the autosuggestion show `From this website`.
As workaround, you need to change the fieldname from `name="email"` to something else, like `name="user-email"`.
And handle the change inside your server logic.

Again in your server logic, generate a random name every time page is shown, like a UUID `autocomplete="c821c4f0-7be8-11eb-9439-0242ac130002"`

### Solution #2:

Replace the input kind `type="email"` to `type="text"`.

**html:**

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-email" name="user-email" placeholder="Enter Email" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" autocomplete="off" />
```

**javascript:**

```js
window.onload = function () {
    init();
}

function init() {
    let x = document.getElementById("user-email");
    if (x) x.setAttribute("type", "email");
}
```

### Solution #3:

Add hidden fields before the real one:
[HTML - Disable Password Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41946532/1049870)

PS: Don't forget to place `autocomplete="off"` on the form which field belongs

Comment: i want to disable the autosuggestion not to  autofill, autofill is alredy done using readonly only property.

Comment: check edited question you didn't understand my question, my issue is not autofill my issue is autosuggestion browser cookie, i want to prevent those via code..

Comment: i try all things to change the fieldname from name="email" to others like name="new-email" or name="email1" or etc... i apply my all logic but cant fixed this autosuggestion issue its also in firefox browsers.

Comment: Added a last resort

Comment: its work for email for change type..but i want to also turn off autosuggestion for password field and i cant change this type to password to text... anyway thanks for your resort