# Can "Manage Password" be disable from an input field?

Tags: angular, input, angular-material, autocomplete, passwords

It's there a way to disable this functionality in 2021?... I have already tried using autocomplete="off", autocomplete =" new-password", and none of this work on an input field of type password and doesn't make the 'Manage Passwords' disappear. I am trying to disable this manager from showing up, I've been searching for a while and I could not found a recent answer here about this topic. The only way to stop it, it's from google chrome settings.
It's there a way to disable this writting some typescript, javascript or something. I am using angular and angular material on this project.
I am so curious if it's there a way to do it... Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html password field - disable the password manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241715/html-password-field-disable-the-password-manager)

Comment: This is a user extension, of course you don't have control over it.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner I've already tried this, but it does not work anymore...thank you

Comment: @LingVu I think you' re right... I was looking for a way to do it  programmatically, but it seems autocomplete attribute has not that power for this