# How can I obfuscate inputs in React but not by using type=password?

Tags: reactjs, input

I was tasked with obfuscating input fields not related to passwords and the common solution of using type `password` is not very user friendly as many browsers e.g. chrome prompt to save password which isn't good UX.

I initially thought I could just use style `-webkit-text-security: disc;` and found that Firefox doesn't support this. I then tried to use `autocomplete="off"` but this is ignored by browsers as a web app should not be able to override browser settings.

I have read many articles and tutorials but they all use type `password`.

I am also very new to React so my searches might be missing good results.

This code is an example of how most solutions I have found handle this problem.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ObfuscateShowHide extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      hidden: true,
    };
    this.toggleShow = this.toggleShow.bind(this);
  }

  toggleShow() {
    this.setState({ hidden: !this.state.hidden });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type={this.state.hidden ? 'password' : 'text'} />
        <button onClick={this.toggleShow}>Peek</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ObfuscateShowHide;
```

I also examined the idea of using a custom font as per this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22457652/1265302) but it was rejected by the team.