# disable save password bubble in chrome using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Is there a way to disable the save password bubble in Chrome using javascript?  I need to make sure no users are able to use that feature.

This is a Chrome specific problem. [The solution offered in a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality) works for Mozilla, but not for Chrome. **I don't want the bubble or option to even show up.** autocomplete=off does not work in Chrome.

Comment: `autocomplete="off"` is not supported in many browsers so the only solution is to simulate `input password` with `input text` by masking text, you can use some kind of js library for that , check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769429/get-input-type-text-to-look-like-type-password

Answer (score 1):

Set your login form to `autocomplete="off"`:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: it does not seem to work anymore. Even my online banking site now saves the password:) only in chrome. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/zhhj7hCip5c