# how to make text input as password without using type password

Tags: html, css, input

I have to create text box in the html that content don't show like password without using type as password.

I tried using `css -webkit-text-security: disc;` but it did not work.

Comment: Interesting example is [here](http://jsbin.com/juwuy/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769429/get-input-type-text-to-look-like-type-password

Comment: Seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/2udeqpq2/           Make sure you are using a webkit browser too.

Comment: Use some font to show asterisks or simbols, like this http://www.dafont.com/it/estrellas-tfb.font

Answer (score -2):

One way i can think of is to handle onkeydown event of the input field by reassigning the input value to something else other than the typed key.