# Prevent jaws from saying "password" in password-type input fields

Tags: html, passwords, jaws-screen-reader

I have a field which uses a password-type input (`<input type="password">`). It is not a password field but we need it to behave exactly like a password field. Whatever label we add/put in, Jaws reads it as *"what-ever-label password edit ..."*.

How can I prevent Jaws from saying *"password"* so it would only say *"what-ever-label edit ..."* (just not the word *"password"*) without creating a custom password-like field?

Comment: Also, this could be of use:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769429/get-input-type-text-to-look-like-type-password

Comment: firefox does not support the css styke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best solution so far is to add role="textbox" to the password input. Though if there is a text written, JAWS read them as  "what-ever-label edit bullet bullet bullet..." in chrome. This is good for now as it is not reading the exact characters anyway. If there is way to not let JAWS read the text ("bullet bullet") please post your answers here.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: Note to others: This works in Internet Explorer and Edge. But Firefox ESR release (v56 basically) still says the extra 'password'. I haven't managed to make it stop yet.

Comment: Still does not work on chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try using [aria labels.](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-label_to_provide_an_invisible_label)

`<input type="password" aria-label="whatever!">`

Documentation states it would work, let me know!

Comment: It still says the word "password"

Comment: And you have to use `<input type="password">` ? You could use `<input type="text">` with some CSS to create dots

Comment: what's the css for firefox? doesn't support -webkit-text-security nor text-security

Comment: Ouch, that's a really annoying situation. Have you tried using `aria-labeledby` as explained here? https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-labelledby_for_link_purpose

Comment: yes. doing so will only change the label part of the voice prompt, so it will say "whateverlabelfromaria-labelledby password edit..."