# what is the alternative of input[type="password"] for amp pages

Tags: amp-html

how can I replace my input[type="password"] tag to convert into html to amp pages?

User Id 
        Password

Answer (score 0):

`input type=password` is not allowed in AMP.
Find reference [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form)

Comment: Yes, but why?? On that page there even is a type=password in an example.

Comment: I opened a PR to remove it from the sample, you can follow it here https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/9456#issuecomment-303185956.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fake the functionality with a normal text input. But it will never be a real password input. I hope they will relax the amp rules in the future.

From @Shrek

```
<input type="text" class="pw" autocomplete="off">
input.pw {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

However, this will work in browsers that are webkit descendants.. Opera, Chrome and Safari, but not much support for the rest, another solution to this is using webfonts.

Use any font editing utility like [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/) to create a font with all the characters to be * ( or any symbol you want ). Then use CSS web fonts to use them as a custom font.

Source:
[Get input type=text to look like type=password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769429/get-input-type-text-to-look-like-type-password)