# Get input type=password to look like type=text

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input with type=password which I want to show stars like an input with type=text.

```
<input type="password" name=""/>
```

My purpose is to click on the input box when calling the input password when the keyboard, using a lot of methods can not be achieved, so I would like to try this way.

Comment: What do you mean by "show stars like an `input` with `type=text`? AFAIK, `type=text` does not show stars as its characters

Comment: Perhaps you have it backwards? I.e. you want a text input that behaves like a password input?

Comment: please edit your question. it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare CSS for showing Password stars like normal stars.
look into this given reference [CSS script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17769519/7783455) .i think it will help.