# How to make the characters dispalyed in django input text box as not human readable

Tags: django

How to make the characters dispalyed in django input text box as not human readable.

For example, if I have a sensitive field like bank account number, I wanted to show the value as '*********'. Instead of showing the actual value. Just to secure the value

I tried with changing my text input widget to password input, but the problem with that is , it doesnt display '*********' . and form assumes it as an empty value and when I submit it gives error to enter value for it.

Your ideas will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Benny Varughese

Comment: @ Benny Varughese    why not do it like this  ```'*' * len(your-sensitive-date)``` then send it to your template, you can do it in your ```view``` then replace it with the real ```sensetive-data``` then send it to your template

Comment: Related - [Get input type=text to look like type=password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769429/get-input-type-text-to-look-like-type-password)

Comment: Hi Iliya, Thanks for the update. Are you saying to set the form field initial value to masked one in the view ?

Comment: Hi Iliya, I tried by changing the field value to masked one in the view. Problem is my does the view and update. So if the user click the update then it is trying to update with the mask value. Please let me know if you see any work around for this.